# Rails 3: Devise overriding sign_up controller woes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

Referenced the online documents for Devise but my override is still not working. Any one got any suggestions why not? It just goes to the root after sign in. Sign up works though.

**Routes:**

```
  root :to => 'pages#index'
  get "pages/index"

  devise_for :users, :path => 'accounts', :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

  match 'profile' => 'profiles#show', :as => 'current_profile'
  match 'profile/edit' => 'profiles#edit', :as => 'edit_current_profile'
  put 'profile' => 'profiles#update'

  resources :users do
    resources :profiles 
  end
```

**Registration Controller:**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     edit_current_profile_path
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     current_profile_path
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     current_profile_path
  end
```

This goes in the application_controller, not the override class.